# Create page visible only for admins on simple user system in PHP

Tags: php, admin, visibility

I am creating a system where users can add items on a calendar and add reports about competitions. But I want to activate them before they are visible on the website.

I have got a row with kal_active which has to be 1 for the item to be showed (for calendar)
And vers_active which also has to be 1 (for reports).

In the users table I added a row with admin and gave myself a "1" there.

Now my idea is to create a page which is only accessible when admin = 1. I allready have the user content showed when a user is logged in by the following code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
```

But how can I also add an extra option here so it's only showing up when admin = 1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like this: `if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && $admin == 1){`  `!empty` does exactly the same as `isset` but also checks if the (in this case session) is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Your UAC is a bit simple and hacker-prone but still this should work:

```
public function hasAccess($userId, $appPart) {
    $con = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
    $result = $con->query('SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id=' . $userId);

    $row = mysqli->fetch_object($result);

    switch ($appPart) {
        case 'kal_active':
            $ret = $row->kal_active == 1;
            break;
        case 'vers_active':
            $ret = $row->vers_active == 1;
            break;
        default:
            $res = false;
            break;
    }

    $result-close();
    $con->close();

    return $res;
}
```

Now you only have to call this function with the id in your session and the desired app-part to check (eg kal_active).